# Why FINE level gives me still DEBUG messages in java log file?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, configuration, catalina

I have tried to change the `logging.properties` file to:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, to log debug messages in ContextConfig and HostConfig
# classes and to log only warnings and errors in other
# org.apache.catalina.** classes, uncomment these lines:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.level = WARNING
```

But for some reason, when I run my server, it is still outputting DEBUG logging such as:

```
> 16:50:01.849 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#23'
```

There is no occurence of `DEBUG` in logging.properties, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 6):

FINE is actually corresponding to DEBUG. If you want to for example INFO, you need to replace FINE by INFO.

You can find all the levels in that link: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your debug line, it seems that you are using `logback`, and this line is related to a class in Spring. The log you see is not the tomcat one, but your application. Look for a `logback.xml` file instead.

Comment: Ok. Is there a folder the tomcat logs are stored in, in that case?

Comment: It will depend on your logback configuration. Do you have a logback.xml file in your project ?

Comment: You must have somewhere a logging configuration file. It may not be logback then, but look for files that could configure your log framework